# How to obtain a user input value from an image input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, syntax

[image: Simple Rock Paper Scissors]

```js
//const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'] in image form
const choices = window.document.getElementsByClassName('Images');
console.log(choices)

var userInput = window.document.getElementsByTagName('input')
console.log(userInput)


//take the image input and use it as a variable for the playerSelection part.
function playerSelection() {
    let answer = prompt('Rock, paper, scissors').toLowerCase()
    return answer
}
```

```html
<div class="Options">
    <input type ="image" class="Images" src ="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/925/925141.svg" alt=""/>
    <input type ="image" class="Images" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2583/2583491.svg" alt style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">
    <input type ="image" class="Images" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/494/494672.svg" alt="">
    </div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is obtain the user input from the HTML file when the user clicks one of the pictures. So I can then later use it in my javascript file and save it into a variable. I've tried the getElementsByTagName but nothing really shows up in the developer console. What I'm not sure of is how can I test for user input using google developer tools, just so that I know my code is operating properly.

Comment: Do you know how to listen for a `click` event on an element?

Answer (score 5):

Image inputs act like buttons. You should give each input a value. Then add a click event listener that gets the value of the button that was clicked.

```js
//const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'] in image form

const output = document.querySelector("#output");
const choices = document.querySelectorAll('.Images');

choices.forEach(i => i.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playerSelection(this.value)
}));

//take the image input and use it as a variable for the playerSelection part.
function playerSelection(answer) {
  output.innerText = answer;
}
```

```css
.Images {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Options">
  <input type="image" value="rock" class="Images" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/925/925141.svg" alt="" />
  <input type="image" value="paper" class="Images" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2583/2583491.svg" alt style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">
  <input type="image" value="scissors" class="Images" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/494/494672.svg" alt="">
</div>
You selected: <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Hmm I kind of understand what's going on, but what does adding the value do exactly for the input tag?

Comment: It allows you to tell which input was clicked on by using `this.value`.